# Percentage SSRS - two datasets

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, percentage

I've had a look at several questions which are answered on here and I seem to be doing it right bu the percentage is coming out a little different than expected.

Here's the expression:

```
=SUM(Fields!Dig_Team.Value,"PivotTable_1") / COUNT(Fields!Dig.Value,"Form_Count")
```

I am just looking for the percentage difference between the two. PivotTable_1 has the "total" and "Form Count" is the number difference I am trying to work out.

Pivot is a total from a pivot table and the Count dataset is just a basic COUNT([Table]) field.

As it stands two values to work from are:

```
Pivot = 175      Count = 16
```

My percentage shows as `8.21%` (formatted the text box field as percentage)

Calculators and websites show this should be around 9.1%..

Any help or ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: I also meant to add, I've tried * 100 like calculators do but this makes the number go all over the place unless I am ordering it all wrong..

Comment: If you wanted count as a percentage of pivot then it's just Count/Pivot which give you 0.0914  (or 9.1% when formatted)

Answer (score 0):

Figured I could just use the totals which are output by the report.

```
=ReportItems!Textbox127.Value / ReportItems!Barrierman1.Value
```